# Pandas Group By and Counting Occurrences that are Strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe and am trying to group it by division and get the counts of it based on a column which here I call "Question". It's got some null values which I want to include. It only has Yes/No response.

I've been experimenting with the groupby function and it's not looking how I want it to look. I also thought of making separate dataframes based on the string responses of "Question" and merging based on the division but it's not working out either.

Here is what I have

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Division', 'Question'], dropna=False)['Division'].count().to_frame(name='Total')
```

My results end up as:

```
Division   Question   Total
name1      nan         1
name2      No          3
...
name20     Yes         1
name20     No          1
name20     nan         2
```

I've tried using this but it uses the total nulls from that column as the counts and I want it based on 'Question' == 'Yes' or 'Question' == 'No' or 'Question' == 'nan'

```
df2['Null_Counts'] = df.loc[:, 'Question'].isnull().sum()

Division   Question   Total   Null_Counts
name1      nan         1      20 
name2      No          3      20
...
name20     Yes         1      20
name20     No          1      20
name20     nan         2      20
```

I am trying to figure out how to make the "Question" column as separate columns so that it groups by Division & Question.  I want to include the null values so it would like:

```
Division   Null_Counts   Yes_Counts   No_Counts   Total
name1      1             nan          nan         1
name2      3             nan          nan         3
...        ...           ..           ...         ...
name20      2             1            1           4
```

I do not care if it reads empty counts as nan but it can be zero.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal data example? Without it I can only advise you to take a look at the [.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) method, which will allow you to use your own function to group the answers the way you want. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

basically, i find that replacing the `np.nan` with a string is cleaner (works quickly). It also comes with the benefit that the df contains zero's in place of `nan` when the total is zero.

so this works:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = {'Division': ['name1', 'name2', 'name20', 'name20', 'name20'],
        'Question': [np.nan, 'No', 'Yes', 'No', np.nan],
        'Total': [1, 3, 1, 1, 2]}  

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Replace NaN with 'unsure'
df['Question'] = df['Question'].fillna('unsure')

df = (df.pivot_table(index='Division', 
                    columns='Question',
                    values='Total', 
                    aggfunc='sum')
       .fillna(0)
       .reset_index())

# Convert columns to integers
df = df.astype({'No': 'int', 'Yes': 'int', 'unsure': 'int'})

df['total'] = df['No'] + df['Yes'] + df['unsure']

print(df)
```

which return this:

```
Question Division  No  Yes  unsure  total
0           name1   0    0       1      1
1           name2   3    0       0      3
2          name20   1    1       2      4
```

From here you can edit the column headers yourself...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying to do things a simpler way based on critcal thinking, instead of trying to find the perfect function or shortest block of code. IMO .isnull, .fillna, and np.nan all have their own quirks, but for your application you can avoid directly assessing nan values at all with a simple if-elif-else. Once you get that working you can worry about efficiency. This approach also makes it *much* easier to adapt to a similar task in another language.

```
# Creating a sample DataFrame
data = {
    'Division': ['name1', 'name1', 'name2', 'name20', 'name2', 'name1', 'name20', 'name20', 'name1'],
    'Question': ['nan', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'nan', 'No', 'Yes']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Initialize an empty list to store dictionaries for each division
result_data = []

# Iterate through the DataFrame by Division
for division, group_df in df.groupby('Division'):
    # Initialize counts
    null_counts = 0
    yes_counts = 0
    no_counts = 0
    
    # Iterate through group_df
    for question_value in group_df['Question']:           
        if question_value == 'Yes':
            yes_counts += 1
        elif question_value == 'No':
            no_counts += 1
        else:
            null_counts += 1 # don't mess with .isnull or any of that
    
    # Calculate the total count
    total_count = yes_counts + no_counts
    
    # Create a dictionary for the current division
    result_dict = {
        'Division': division,
        'Null_Counts': null_counts,
        'Yes_Counts': yes_counts,
        'No_Counts': no_counts,
        'Total': total_count
    }
    
    # Append the dictionary to the result_data list
    result_data.append(result_dict)

# Create a new DataFrame from the list of dictionaries
result_df = pd.DataFrame(result_data)

# Display the result DataFrame
print(result_df)
```

Comment: Nice method. However, the for loop is not as good as the vectorised method...

Answer (score 0):

Using the sample data provided in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77217272/6394617)

```
df = df.groupby('Division').Question.value_counts().unstack()
df['Total'] = df.sum(axis=1)

print(df)

Question   No  Yes  nan  Total
Division                      
name1     2.0  1.0  1.0    4.0
name2     1.0  1.0  NaN    2.0
name20    1.0  1.0  1.0    3.0
```